# How can i use if statment with flutter locale to show class

Tags: flutter

i have read this article 
https://medium.com/saugo360/managing-locale-in-flutter-7693a9d4d6ac

and i try to make if that will show other class if you use X lang for example:

if(_getLanguageCode(context) !='en') return Myclass()

this my getlanguagecode:

```
_getLanguageCode(BuildContext context) {
  return Localizations.localeOf(context).languageCode;
}
```

hope can help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show a page only if the language code is different than 'en' you can define a MaterialPageRoute and push it via Navigator.push .

```
if (_getLanguageCode(context) != 'en') 
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourClass()));
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: I edited my answer, there no big explain to do here, it seems that @user13301788 already know the basics but just want an example